# Run remote files directly in dockerfile

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I am wondering if it is possible to RUN a remote file stored in an NFS share when building an image from a dockerfile.

Currently I am using the COPY command and then the RUN command to execute the files, however many of the files I need to create the image are extremely large.

Is it possible to execute files stored in an NFS share directly in the dockerfile without having to copy them all over?

Answer (score 0):

You can only `RUN` files inside your container - so it needs to copied to your container.

What you can do is move the COPY commands to the beginning of your Dockerfile so that they are cached and don't need to be copied every time you change a command later in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can `RUN curl....` to grab the remote file ,then execute it sure.

But this will only run at image build time, not during lifecycle of the container

You could also mount the NFS volume to your host, then `COPY` the files.

Otherwise, remote execution is a pretty basic security flaw and shouldn't be possible under any circumstances